# `Store does not implement IUserRoleStore.` error with custom UserManager

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1.2. I need create an application with login without Entity Framework. Anything ok but I have a problem when I want `AddToRoleAsync`.

This is my code:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public AccountController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        IEmailSender emailSender,
        ILogger<AccountController> logger)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var x = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.PasswordMd5, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);   

            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(LoginWith2fa), new { returnUrl, model.RememberMe });
            }

            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> System.NotSupportedException: Store does not implement IUserRoleStore.
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.GetUserRoleStore()   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.d__106.MoveNext()
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown

How can I add `AddToRoleAsync` without Entity Framework?

Comment: Authorization isn't tied to EF and the code you posted doesn't use EF anyway. The exception snippet you posted isn't about EF at all, it complains that your custom class doesn't implement the `IUserRoleStore` interface. You haven't posted the full exception text, so I guess it complains about `_userManager`. There's no code for that class either, but it looks like it should implement that interface

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid EF? You have to learn how the authentication/authorization middleware classes work before you can modify them and store credentials somewhere else. If you want to use a database, you'll probably end up duplicating what EF already does. EF supports all major relational databases and a few document databases as well

Comment: Never mind that you may end up significantly weakening your application. That `PasswordMd5` doesn't just smell - MD5 is way beyond broken and trivial to reverse in 2020. I'm not even talking about rainbow tables (precalculated hashes), simply brute forcing this can crack MD5 in a matter of hours. This isn't used for almost 10 years. ASP.NET/Core on the other hand use secure salting and hashing with at least 1000 hashing iterations

Comment: I **strongly** suggest not trying to modify the authentication middleware **at all** before you understand the security implications. What you posted suggests passwords aren't stored securely - in fact [a google search could reveal the password](https://www.troyhunt.com/we-didnt-encrypt-your-password-we-hashed-it-heres-what-that-means/)

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos This is old project. All thing has been build on  ADO using System.Data.SqlClient; Now I want inherit form this library.

Comment: Old projects don't use ASP.NET MVC's (and later)  UserManager. Nor do they use the VB6 ADO technology. Like all .NET projects, including .NET 5, they use ADO.NET. EF Core uses ADO.NET. The error clearly says the problem is with the class. And [MD5 hashes are obsolete for 10 years now](https://www.troyhunt.com/our-password-hashing-has-no-clothes/). Someone went out of his/her way to break the built-in authentication. Probably removed the `IUserRoleStore` implementation as well, or never added it when they created custom classes

Comment: In any case, this has nothing at all to do with EF. It has to do with the modifications someone made to a *not old* ASP.NET Core 2.2 project. We can't guess what's going on with code that wasn't posted. Customizing ASP.NET Core's Identity is documented though. Check [Custom storage providers for ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: [From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.2#reconfigure-app-to-use-a-new-storage-provider) it looks like you can register a role store separately from the user store and manager classes. This means you use the built-in `RoleStore<TRole>` class even if the other stores don't use EF.

Comment: If you don't want to add EF Core to the application (why???) you'll have to [create a new RoleStore class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.2#customize-the-role-store) that implements [IRoleStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.irolestore-1?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and implement all methods